# When mysql updates a non-indexed column，why can use the primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, sql-execution-plan

MySQL version is 8.0.23

Create table and insert data

```sql
CREATE TABLE `test_update` (
  `id`      int         NOT NULL ,
  `column1` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `column2` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

insert into test_update values (1, 'a', 'test1');
insert into test_update values (2, 'b', 'test2');
insert into test_update values (3, 'c', 'test3');
insert into test_update values (4, 'd', 'test4');
insert into test_update values (5, 'e', 'test5');
insert into test_update values (6, 'f', 'test6');
insert into test_update values (7, 'g', 'test7');
insert into test_update values (8, 'h', 'test8');
insert into test_update values (9, 'i', 'test9');
insert into test_update values (10,'j', 'test10');
```

When i select column1 by use column2,explain show mysql use scan full table,i think it is reasonable

```sql
mysql> explain select column1 from test_update where column2='test8';
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table       | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test_update | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   10 |    10.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

But when i update column1, explain show mysql use the primary key,it is a non-indexed column, Why is this?

```sql
mysql> explain update test_update set column1='z' where column2='test8';
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table       | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | UPDATE      | test_update | NULL       | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |   10 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Primary index is clustered one, scanning it and scanning the table is the same. It is used in UPDATE because the server must primarily gather PK values of the rows to be updated, then update them.

Comment: @Hedwig . . . The number of rows is so small that MySQL may decide that an index is not useful for the `select`.  Because of locking and logging, indexes usage is different for `update`s.  You might want to try this on a table with thousands of rows rather than 10.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, that's not how I read the question. the where clause in both cases doesn't include a column with an index - why would "column2='test8'" use an index on the primary key?

Comment: @Akina So, mysql still scans the full table for updates？

Comment: In shown case - of course.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ,I insert 40,000 of rows into the table, the explain is still the same

Answer (score 0):

The optimal index for the Select is

```
INDEX(column2,   -- to handle the WHERE test
      column1)   -- for "covering"
```

That would also be useful for the Update, though for different reasons.

With that `INDEX`, `select column1 from t where column2='test8'` will touch 2 rows (in your sample data) in the index's BTree, and no rows in the data's BTree

- The one row with `column2='test8'`.  (There could have been be zero or multiple rows here.)
- One more row to discover that there are no more rows with `column2='test8'`.

And because the only other column in the `SELECT` is part of the index, the index is sufficient ("Covering" == "Using index").

Similarly for the Update, 1+1 rows will be read and 1 will be updated.

In Explain, sometimes "Type = INDEX" is misleading.  Note that "Key" is "PRIMARY".  It is really doing a table scan in this case.  A further clue of that is that "Rows" is "10", which is an approximation of the number of rows in the entire table.

More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

As for Updating using the PK, I would say:  "Since there is not useful index, the Update must scan the table looking for all rows matching the `WHERE`.  For each such row, it will perform the Update.

Comment: Does it mean that mysql still scanned the full table?

Comment: @Hedwig - No.  I updated my Answer to elaborate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,i know that covering index is a better choice,i just curious about why the primary key is used in the update in this example

Comment: @Hedwig - For the `UPDATE`, the "PRIMARY" and "index" are misleading, yet technically 'correct'.  The update had to scan the entire table, which is "indexed" by the "PRIMARY" key.  (I agree that it is confusing.)